# What is a composite type in C?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

From [§6.2.7.5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (page 66):

> EXAMPLE Given the following two file scope declarations:
>
> ```
> int f(int (*)(), double (*)[3]);  
> int f(int (*)(char *), double (*)[]);
> ```
>
> The resulting composite type for the function is:
>
> ```
> int f(int (*)(char *), double (*)[3]);
> ```

Above the example, they explain that a composite type is a type, compatible with two different types. I would intuitively understand the phrase "composite type" as meaning "structures and unions", which appears to be way off-target.

*What is a composite type in C and what is it used for? Could someone please explain the example above in details?*

Comment: I think you mean §6.2.7?

Comment: Did you consider scrolling up to the text above that example (6.2.7/3) where, surprisingly, the definition of composite type is stated?

Comment: Yes, 6.2.7, my mistake. I read the definition (twice), but did not understand it. I am actually even confused as to how "double (*)[3]" would be used.

Comment: Does it help to say that the composite type is the result of the unification of the two types?

Comment: @Vorac `double(*)[3]` is an array of pointers, which has 3 elements. What don't you get about that?

Comment: @TonyTheLion No, `double (*)[3]` is a pointer to an array of 3 `double`.

Comment: @TonyTheLion No it isn't, it is an array pointer to an array of double with 3 elements

Comment: @Tony The Lion, for example where do I put the variable name in order to declare objects of this type. Inside the parentheses? But really - *what are composite types **for***?

Comment: @DanielFischer oh thanks, I can't believe I still mix them up. Damn :|

Comment: Can someone explain, how a function taking a function with `char *` parameter can be a composite type for a function that takes a function without parameters? I would expect the opposite given LSP, co- / contravariance rules: you pass a function that does not expect parameters, and if a parameter is in fact passed, it will be ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would intuitively understand the phrase "composite type" as meaning "structures and unions", which appears to be way off-target.

In the C language definition, arrays and structs are *aggregate* types (types composed of multiple elements).  Unions are kind of their own animal, since they can only take on the value of one element at a time.

*Composite* types are more of an issue for compiler implementors, rather than us run-of-the-mill code monkeys.  You and I would not attempt to define a composite type, or declare objects of that type.

In the example given, you have two file scope declarations for a function `f` that are slightly different from each other.  Based on the rules presented in 6.2.7/3, the compiler determines a type that works for both, such that it can enforce type semantics at compile time (i.e., any calls to `f` can be properly checked, even with the slightly different declarations) and generate the proper machine code to call the function.

Answer (score 11):

I'm probably not the right person to answer this, but for what it is worth, here is the C99 rationale, which may be helpful:

> 6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type
>
> The concepts of compatible type and composite type were introduced to allow C89 to discuss those
>   situations in which type declarations need not be identical. These
>   terms are especially useful in explaining the relationship between an
>   incomplete type and a completed type. With the addition of variable
>   length arrays (§6.7.5.2) in C99, array type compatibility was extended
>   so that variable length arrays are compatible with both an array of
>   known constant size and an array with an incomplete type.
>
> Structure, union, or enumeration type declarations in two different
>   translation units do not formally declare the same type, even if the
>   text of these declarations come from the same header file, since
>   the translation units are themselves disjoint. The Standard thus
>   specifies additional compatibility rules for such types so that two
>   such declarations are compatible if they are sufficiently similar.
>
> QUIET CHANGE IN C99
>
> Structures or union type declarations in different translation units
>   now must have identical tags to be compatible.