Some issues about composite types in C
C11  6.2.7 p3：

If both types are array types, the following rules are applied:

If one type is an array of known constant size, the composite type is an array of that size.

Otherwise, if one type is a variable length array whose size is specified by an expression that is not evaluated, the behavior is
undefined.

Otherwise, if one type is a variable length array whose size is specified, the composite type is a variable length array of that size.

Otherwise, if one type is a variable length array of unspecified size, the composite type is a variable length array of unspecified
size.

Otherwise, both types are arrays of unknown size and the composite type is an array of unknown size.



For this paragraph, I have the following several questions：

Could you give an example of the application of "Otherwise, if one type is a variable length array whose size is specified by an expression that is not evaluated, the behavior is undefined"?

If there are two variable length array types with specified sizes, then which size of the variable length array type is the composite type?
Just like the following code:


int n=2;
int m=3;
void f(char(*)[n]);
void f(char(*)[m]);

What is the composite type of the function f?
Thank you for your reading.

Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417928/what-is-a-composite-type-in-c (The values of n and m do not matter in the given context.)

The types need to be compatible, see 6.7.6.2p6

@n. m. could be an AI:I think 6.7.6.2p6 only provides explanations for cases where the size specifiers in arrays are integer constant expressions. It doesn't cover the situation of VLA. Well, sorry,did I misunderstand somewhere? I think char()[n] and char()[m] are compatible.

@Dúthomhas:Forgive me. I read the link you gave, but I still can't understand. Could you elaborate on it, please?

There are no composite types in this case as your parameter is not an array, only a pointer to an array and those two are incompatible.

Consider the difference in pointer arithmetic between char (*)[n] and char (*)[m] where n != m.

@David C. Rankin:Do you mean that the two pointers are not compatible? If so, my understanding of this is that the types pointed to by both pointers are VLA, VLA is compatible with any array of compatible element type., so the two pointers are compatible. Are there any problems with my understanding?

@0___________:C11  6.2.7 P3 : "These rules apply recursively to the types from which the two types are derived."  My understanding of this sentence is that this means that although the parameter of the function is of pointer type, it still has a compound type because it is a pointer type (VM) derived from VLA.Moreover, the types pointed to by both pointers are VLA, VLA is compatible with any array of compatible element type, so the two pointers are compatible. Are there any problems with my understanding?

@user24723440 pointer is not derived from the array. Here is an error in your logic.

"If the two array types are used in a context which requires them to be compatible, it is undefined behavior if the two size specifiers evaluate to unequal values."

@0___________:A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object type, called the referenced type.This pointer points to VLA. If it is not derived from an array, then from what is it derived?I think one of us has committed a matter of principle.

@n. m. could be an AI:Immediately following the previous text, I think this sentence still refers to the situation of non-VLA.VLA is compatible with any array of compatible element type.In fact, up to now, I still don't know where I was wrong.

The situation with non-VLA where both dimensions are present is completely dealt with in the preceding text. The passage I quote deals with VLA and covers your code. VLA may be compatible with any array of compatible element type, but the behaviour is still undefined, there is no contradiction.

@user24723440 - the problem you are having is separating 6.3.2.1(p3} array-pointer conversion from your declarations of char (*)[[m] and char (*)[n] that are just plain old pointers to an array of [m] elements. n.m. gave you the citation to the sections that says if m != n then the arrau types are not compatible - full-stop. Your pointers char (*)[[m] and char (*)[n] are not compatible because they are not the same type. (++ would be very different between the two)

@David C. Rankin:You mean that you still think these two pointers are not compatible. Well, maybe I'm wrong, but currently I don't think so. I will raise a new question based on this to solve this problem. You are welcome to point out my mistakes.

@n. m. could be an AI: What you said makes sense. Thank you.

@user24723440 That's what I'm saying. Take for example char (*p)[m] and char (*q)[n]. p is a pointer to an array of m characters, while q is a pointer to an array of n characters. p += 1 advances the address held by p by m bytes while q += 1 advances the address held by q by n bytes. They are not compatibles. However dereferencing p or q by operations of 6.3.2.1(p3} results in *p and *q being compatible because they are both converted to char* at that point.

@DavidC.Rankin: char (*p)[m] and char (*q)[n] are compatible, because char [m] and char [n] are compatible. C 2018 6.7.6.2 6 says “For two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible element types, and if both size specifiers are present, and are integer constant expressions, then both size specifiers shall have the same constant value.” These two types satisfy “have compatible element type” and, because their size specifiers are not integer constant expressions, satisfy “if both size specifiers are present, and are integer constant expressions…” However,…

… if a program attempts to use them where they must be compatible, and m is not equal to n, then the behavior is not defined, since the paragraph continues “If the two array types are used in a context which requires them to be compatible, it is undefined behavior if the two size specifiers evaluate to unequal values.” Thus, the standard gives us a situation in which two array types are compatible but no behavior is defined for making use of that fact. (A C implementation could extend the standard by providing a definition.)

Perhaps inartfully stated, but my point was typeof p != typeof q.  I agree the arrays are compatible, but how does that, in and of itself, make the pointers compatible?. I agree with all you said about 6.7.2 6 (that's the standard), but I don't follow the reasoning that because char[m] and char[n] are compatible character arrays, pointers to those arrays are made compatible even in m and n differ. In that case you could not reference elements of p with a pointer of type q or vice versa without running afoul of strict aliasing.

@David C. Rankin: 6.7.6.1 p2 :  For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.  In the above example, two pointers are compatible only if they point to compatible types.

@user24723440 agreed, but the way I read 6.7.6.2 (p9 Example 13) is that m must equal n or they are not compatible. (where the example involving r requires the outermost expression to be equal to be compatible -- n == 6 and m = n + 1 in that case).  Good section to flesh out -- it is another model of clarity rivaling that of the strict aliasing rule 6.5 (p6&7). Both take more than a sitting to digest....


1.Could you give an example of the application of "Otherwise, if one type is a variable length array whose size is specified by an expression that is not evaluated, the behavior is undefined"?

The result type of the conditional operator A ? B : C, is determined by the types of the second and third operands. If they are both pointers to compatible types, “the result type is a pointer to an appropriately qualified version of the composite type” (C 2018 6.5.15 6).
Consider 1 ? (char (*)[]) 0 : (char (*)[foo()]) 0. The second operand type is pointer to an array of an unspecified number of char. The third operand is a pointer to a variable length array. However, since the first operand is 1, the third operand is not evaluated. So the result type would be a composite type involving a type that is a variable length array whose size is specified by an expression that is not evaluated.
(While this is demonstrated here by converting zero to a pointer type, the situation arises in real code from time to time and is the subject of an open Clang bug.)

2.If there are two variable length array types with specified sizes, then which size of the variable length array type is the composite type?

I do not see this specified in the C 2018 standard. I think there may be no situation where a composite type is formed from two variable length array types whose sizes are both evaluated.
For example, with the conditional operator, at most one operand is evaluated. For a declaration of a function, size expressions are evaluated only upon entry to the function, so the size expressions in the function definition are used, and size expressions in any non-definition declarations are not used.

The example you gave is very good. Thank you. But I still have a doubt. If there is 1? ( char (*) [3] )0 : ( char (*) [n] )0, I think the composite type is char(*)[3], because it is judged directly based on the first rule. For the example you gave, I think it can also be judged directly using the first rule. Maybe the second rule is not needed at all?

@user24723440: You are right. I changed the second operand to an a pointer to an array of unspecified size. This is not determined by the first rule, so the second applies. It could also be char (*)[bar()], another pointer to a variable-length array.

Your edits seem to have made the example incompatible with the sentence after it.
